# Dynamic Positioning of HTML Elements

Tags: html, css

I have a website that works fine, looks okay, etc. The problem is I am not the best with positioning, float, etc. Instead of elements just lining up one under another, I have to manually set increasingly large margins for each additional paragraph I add.

My navbar is composed of a ul inside a fixed div. The ul is not floating, but the "li"s are. I need a way to position this and the other elements such that everything is below the navbar. I have tried using clear: both; to no avail. I know my positioning is all over the place, I don't really understand how/if positioning and float are inherited.

Here is a link to the [website](http://users.admin.illinois.edu/jmontagu/public_html/index.html).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webfonts/stylesheet.css">
        <title>
            Artwork
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
        <img src="images/navbar/title.png" class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="art.html">Art</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 id="header">Welcome to my Website!</h1>
        <p>
            The purpose of this website is to showcase my artwork, and, in a way, my HTML skills. Click on
            one of the links up top, and you can see some of my <b>artwork</b> or maybe learn <b>about me</b>!
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #009900;
}

div.navbar{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    background-image:url('images/navbar/navbar.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#header{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-family: 'League Gothic', sans-serif;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

img.navbar{
    float: left;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
display: block;
width: 120px;
font-weight:  500;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
color:  #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
margin: 0px;
text-decoration:  none;
}

li{
    float: left;
{
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah instead of giving margin manually for everything why don't you use margin for whole wrapper the contents that follows fixed nav-bar [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/XLQ8Z/11/)

```
.nav-bar{
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
     background-color:#000;
     width:100%;
     position:fixed;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
 }

.content{
    margin-top:75px;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="nav-bar">
    <h1>
        topbar
    </h1>
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>tow</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h2>content</h2>
    <p>hi hello ouyasd asdasda dasdasd</p>
     <p>hi hello ouyasd asdasda dasdasd</p>
     <p>hi hello ouyasd asdasda dasdasd</p>
     <p>hi hello ouyasd asdasda dasdasd</p>
</div>
```